# How to return a Task?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am learning Websocket from: https://radu-matei.com/blog/aspnet-core-websockets-middleware/ How do I return from a Task below?

```
public override Task ReceiveAsync(WebSocket socket, WebSocketReceiveResult result, byte[] buffer)
    {
        string message = "Replied by: " + cn.GetId(socket);

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await socket.SendAsync(buffer: new ArraySegment<byte>(array: Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message),
                                                                 offset: 0,
                                                                 count: message.Length),
                                  messageType: WebSocketMessageType.Text,
                                  endOfMessage: true,
                                  cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);


        });
    }
```

I got: Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0161  'NotificationsMessageHandler.ReceiveAsync(WebSocket, WebSocketReceiveResult, byte[])': not all code paths return a value

and I don't know how to return a Task..

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Task.Run explicitly, Instead of

```
Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await socket.SendAsync(buffer: new ArraySegment<byte>(array: Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message),
                                                             offset: 0,
                                                             count: message.Length),
                              messageType: WebSocketMessageType.Text,
                              endOfMessage: true,
                              cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);


    });
```

you can just use

```
await socket.SendAsync(buffer: new ArraySegment<byte>(array: Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message),
                                                         offset: 0,
                                                         count: message.Length),
                          messageType: WebSocketMessageType.Text,
                          endOfMessage: true,
                          cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);
```

here, await will return the result of socket.SendAsync which i am assuming is asynchronous

Comment: I got error:

NotificationsMessageHandler.ReceiveAsync(WebSocket, WebSocketReceiveResult, byte[])': not all code paths return a value

Comment: +1: You should also mention that **_not_** using `Task.Run` has different behavior in that it `Task.Run` schedules the work to run on another thread. In the context of the question, there's definitely no need for `Task.Run`.

Comment: @DevDon, use return await

Comment: You can't use `return await` because the method is not `async`.

Comment: @John, Judging by method name SendAsync, i am assuming it is async and ReceiveAsync should be async, thanks for mentioning.

Comment: OP's `ReceiveAsync` signature: `public override Task ReceiveAsync` - The `async` keyword is missing. OP needs to change it to `public override async Task ReceiveAsync` in order to use `await` in that method. –